# On product server, connecting to mySql often fails

Tags: php, mysql

On product server, connecting to mySql often fails, "Can't connect to MySQL server on xxx" but the site works well, just sometimes "mysql server has gone away". I tried mysql_connect even mysql_pconnect.

Comment: I suggest you start digging through the log files: messages log, mysql log, http error log, ...

Comment: and if I dont have accesses to them?

Comment: If you don't have access to the server logs you're presumably using a shared hosting service. Ask their support team.

Comment: Then there is little we can do to help you, since without any information all that is left is to _guess_.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to answer to this question because there can be really a lot of reasons for the error, the best description of the problem can be found in [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html).

You should be able to further investigate the issue by going through MySQL logs or we might be able to help you if you actually posted problematic MySQL logs here.